# Is there any transparent see material that can endure temperatures of 2000 °C?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics, heat, decomposition

I was wondering if there is a transparent material that can endure temperatures up to 2000 °C without deforming or degrading. This material doesn't have to be glass, it can be plastic or a weirdly transparent alloy.

Comment: The 1978 Pioneer Venus probe had sapphire windows (and a diamond window) with melting points above that temperature.

Answer (score 6):

Although it was a plot point [in a fictional movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_IV:_The_Voyage_Home), ... there is now such a thing as 'transparent aluminium' - [Aluminium oxynitride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxynitride). More exactly, it is an aluminium ceramic composed of Al, O, and N in some proportions.

Looks like it has a melting point of ~2150 °C - so fits the temperature range.

edit: As various commenters have pointed out, sapphire (aluminium oxide) would also do, as might the suggestions from this answer:

https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16177/transparent-material-which-could-withstand-high-temperatures

Comment: At 95% of melt I would not bet it doesn’t deform easily…

Comment: The patent for it was issued before the movie came out, so I would guess they based it on science rather than imagination.

Comment: More commonly available would be sapphire which is  pure aluminium oxide and melts just above 2000 C. It is also a very tough material. Its used in the lab for its excellent optical quality and ability to withstand v. high pressures.

Comment: Magnesium oxide, MgO, melts at 2800C Possibly could be built up by vapor deposition. IS there an actual application